# Is this code behavior defined?

Tags: c++, operators

What does the following code print to the console?

```
map<int,int> m;
m[0] = m.size();
printf("%d", m[0]);
```

Possible answers:

1. The behavior of the code is not defined since it is not defined which statement `m[0]` or `m.size()` is being executed first by the compiler. So it could print `1` as well as `0`.
2. It prints `0` because the right hand side of the assignment operator is executed first.
3. It prints `1` because the `operator[]` has the highest priority of the complete statement `m[0] = m.size()`. Because of this the following sequence of events occurs:

   - `m[0]` creates a new element in the map
   - `m.size()` gets called which is now `1`
   - `m[0]` gets assigned the previously returned (by m.size()) `1`
4. *The real answer?*, which is unknown to me^^

Comment: Well, it certainly has got nothing to do with the priority of the `[]` operator since that is irrelevant here. Apart from that, I don’t know the answer. Good question.

Comment: +1 For a really good question

Comment: as with most of these questions, why would you ever do this anyway?

Comment: @jk: for the sake of curiosity. It's good to know the limits of the language, so you can steer well clear of them in real code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe it's *unspecified* whether 0 or 1 is stored in `m[0]`, but it's not undefined behavior.

The LHS and the RHS can occur in either order, but they're both function calls, so they both have a sequence point at the start and end. There's no danger of the two of them, collectively, accessing the same object without an intervening sequence point.

The assignment is actual int assignment, not a function call with associated sequence points, since `operator[]` returns `T&`. That's briefly worrying, but it's not modifying an object that is accessed anywhere else in this statement, so that's safe too. It's accessed within `operator[]`, of course, where it is initialized, but that occurs before the sequence point on return from `operator[]`, so that's OK. If it wasn't, `m[0] = 0;` would be undefined too!

However, the order of evaluation of the operands of `operator=` is not specified by the standard, so the actual result of the call to `size()` might be 0 or 1 depending which order occurs.

The following would be undefined behavior, though. It doesn't make function calls and so there's nothing to prevent `size` being accessed (on the RHS) and modified (on the LHS) without an intervening sequence point:

```
int values[1];
int size = 0;

(++size, values[0] = 0) = size;
/*     fake m[0]     */  /* fake m.size() */
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the call to `operator []` and the call to `clear` in this statement. Consequently, the behaviour *should* be undefined.

Comment: There are at least 4 sequence points in the statement, one each at the start and end of the function calls to `size()` and `operator[]`.

Comment: @Steve true but they are irrelevant for the relative evaluation order of the statement before and after the equality sign.

Comment: Interesting. The article you link to does say: "(In C++, overloaded operators act like functions, and thus operators that have been overloaded introduce sequence points in the same way as function calls.)".This would make [] operator a sequence point.

Comment: @Arkadiy See the answer to Steve’s comment.

Answer (score 2):

It *does* print 1, and without raising a warning(!) using gcc. It *should* raise a warning because it is undefined.

The precedence class of both `operator[]` and `operator.` is 2 whereas the precedence class of `operator=` is 16.
This means that it is well-defined that `m[0]` and `m.size()` will be executed before the assignment. However, it is not defined which one executes first.

Comment: Would it be different if the precedence of `operator[]` and `operator.` would not be the same?

Comment: @Woltan: no, it's only relevant that both have a higher precedence than `operator=`, so that both subexpressions are evaluated (in unspecified order) before the assignment. If either had a lower precedence than `operator=`, then the expression would have a different meaning anyway (if it's still well-formed).

Comment: @Woltan: no. Precedence is used to work out how to add parentheses to disambiguate an expression. So `m[0] = m.size()` is equivalent to `(m[0]) = (m.size())`, and *not* for example `(m[0] = m).size()`, because `[]` and `.` bind tighter than `=`. But precedence does not determine what order sub-expressions are evaluated across the whole expression - a precedence 2 operator can be evaluated before a precedence 1 operator provided that neither uses the result of the other.

Comment: First, it's unspecified, not undefined.  And there's nothing a compiler could see which would allow it to know that it's unspecified, so the compiler can't complain.  And C++ doesn't have precedence classes, and the precedence is irrelevant here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Given that C++17 is pretty much here, I think it's worth mentioning that this code now exhibits well defined behavior under the new standard. For this case of `=` being the built-in assignment to an integer:

[[expr.ass]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ass#1):

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all
>   group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result
>   in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all
>   cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the
>   right and left operands, and before the value computation of the
>   assignment expression. **The right operand is sequenced before the left
>   operand.** With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call,
>   the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation.

Which leaves us with only one option, and that is #2.